# Pandas Dataframe: Divide Column entries by number of occurence

Tags: pandas, dataframe, division

my Problem:

I have this DF:

```
df_problem = pd.DataFrame({"Share":['5%','6%','9%','9%', '9%'],"level_1":[0,0,1,2,3], 'BO':['Nestle', 'Procter', 'Nestle', 'Tesla', 'Jeff']})
```

The Problem is, that the 9% are actually divided by the three shareholders. So I want to giv each of them their share of 3% and put it to their names. It then should look like this:

```
df_solution = pd.DataFrame({"Share":['5%','6%','3%','3%', '3%'],"level_1":[0,0,0,1,2], 'BO': ['Nestle', 'Procter', 'Nestle', 'Tesla', 'Jeff']})
```

How do I do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
f_problem['Share'] = (f_problem['Share'].str.replace('%', '').astype(float) / 
                      f_problem.groupby('Share')['BO'].
                      transform('count')).astype(str) + '%'

>>> f_problem
      Share     level_1       BO
   0  5.0%        0       Nestle
   1  6.0%        0       Procter
   2  3.0%        1       Nestle
   3  3.0%        2       Tesla
   4  3.0%        3       Jeff
```

Please note that I have assumed that the value of the column 'Share' to be float as you could see above.